# May one make a siyum on a day he is fasting?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, siyum

If a person accepted a personal fast, is he allowed to make a siyum on that day even though he is fasting and won't eat? Also, is there something special about a personal fast day (other than not eating) that precludes someone from making a siyum?

Comment: If one can make a siyum on taanis bechorim wouldn't it be kal v'chomer that one could do it on a personal fast?

Comment: do you mean a siyum which would exempt others from fasting or do you ask whether the simcha of a siyum is contradicted by whatever the somberness is that motivated the fast?

Comment: @yoel i would include that in my question, meaning if the mesayeim isn't going to eat can he still make the siyum?

Comment: @yoel, on the other hand, if he *chose* to fast on a particular day when he didn't have to, perhaps we are more stringent than for a community fast that has an established exemption?  (I can see arguments either way.)

Comment: What do you think the problem might be?

Comment: There are a few different things that you could be asking here, and I'm not sure which it is. 1: Can a person who accepted a personal fast make a siyum to cancel out his own fast? 2: Can a person make a siyum even though he is fasting and won't eat? 3: Is there something special about a personal fast day (other than not eating) that precludes someone from making a siyum?

Comment: @Daniel #s 2 and 3

Answer (score 3):

There is a custom to fast on a yahrzeit unless it is on a yom tov. There is also a custom to make a siyum. I have seen once a rov making a siyum just before the end of the day and eating afterwards a seudo for the siyum attended by many people.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It's a pseudo-seudo.